# 【Eclipse】実行構成のVM引数は実行可能jarファイル作成時に情報として含まれるのか

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

<開発環境>
OS:windows7
java:java SE1.7
eclipse:3.4.2

<概要>
windows環境で開発したjavaプログラムを実行可能jarファイルにして、linuxでクーロンを使用して実行しています
windows環境ではVM引数にフォルダパスを設定して実行していましたが、そのまま実行可能jarファイルにしてlinux環境に移すと実行できませんでした
現在実行環境停止中のため詳細なエラーログは貼れませんが、log4jのプロセス作成エラーがでていました
log4jが読み込めていない為かと思い、
vm引数をすべて削除後に実行可能jarファイルを作ると、linux環境でも問題なく実行できました

わかりづらい説明and質問になりますが、
実行構成に設定するvm引数はjar作成時に引数として含まれるのでしょうか？

Comment: 本家のこれが参考になりますかね？
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689692/default-arguments-in-jar-manifest

Comment: fkmさん
コメントありがとうございます
語学力が乏しいので、リンク先を完璧に解釈できませんでした...
ecliplseで設定したvm引数はjar生成時にきちんと情報として引き渡されて、jar実行時にJVMの設定として適用されるということですかね
マニュフェストファイル等の中身をみてみましたが、eclipseで指定したvm引数の設定等は記述されていませんでした
上記の解釈で正しいとするなら、eclipseで設定したvm引数についての記述がどこにされているのか気になるところです